# How to construct a graph that $2\chi(G)=\chi(G∗G) $

Tags: graph-theory

I asked the flowing question on [mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/q/263721/90655) but its appears to be off-topic.

Is it possible to construct a new graph $G∗G$ from two copy of given graph $G$ such that $2\chi(G)=\chi(G∗G)$ where $\chi(G)$ is chromatic number of graph $G$?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $G + H$ be a graph $X = \overline{\overline{G} \cup \overline{H}}$ with vertex set $V(X) = V(G) \cup V(H)$ and edge set
    $$E(X) = E(G) \cup \{\,\{\,u, v\,\} \forall u \in V(G), v \in V(H)\,\} \cup E(H),$$
Then $\chi(G + G) = 2\chi(G)$.